# How can I offer to others to show my website content in their website?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to know the method by which I can offer others to show my website content in their website by embedding it either by a `script` tag or `iframe`. I have seen some websites showing some content for example a tournament fixture and offer visitor to embed the same content in their websites by copying and pasting the script tag or an `iframe`.

YouTube also offers to embed videos in other websites. Thus the content may be anything like div or table or a video. So how can I do this?

I think [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77442/best-ways-to-generate-an-embed-code) is related to somewhat I am searching. But it doesn't elaborate the solution in detail. I don't know how the external script file will show the content. Note that I am using PHP as a server-side language.

Comment: Stack Overflow is great when you have a specific coding question, but this isn't the site to teach programming concepts and be a general educational theme.

Comment: Have you tried writing an iframe? Share your code here if it's not working and the community will be more than happy to answer your question.

Comment: <iframe style="border:0px" src="url" width="100%" height="100%">
  </iframe>

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I disagree. I've seen numerous questions here which serve as wiki for many topics. The motto of Q&A would have been the original vision of stackoverflow, but now, such questions are too accepted.

Comment: For a start you need to talk to the other websites owners what they areprepared to do. That will affect the answer more than the technicalities

Comment: Can you guys plz help me to solve this question rather than debating with each other? @Jeremy - if STO is not a place to such questions then at where can i learn this? It would be great if you help me rather than teaching me the moto of STO.

Comment: Sachin Because there is no one way to do it, and all of the ways are complicated which varies based upon the back end technology that is used.  Everything from rendering `iframe`s to serving up HTML from a `JSONP` request.

Comment: @Sachin: LcLk has suggested two possible routes. A third, which you link to, references a JavaScript file from your server and then uses JSONP to make cross-domain fetches. So, the user might put a `<div id="video_widget"></div>` in their HTML, link to your script, and then your script reads the HTML to inject into that tag. (Of course, a video is just an example - you can do this with any content).

Comment: I would suggest that you refrain from requesting "step-by-step practical guides" here - that in itself implies that the question is too broad, and needs to be broken down into a pieces that you can deal with individually. So, from my response, do some searching on "JSONP PHP" in a search engine - there are sure to be examples out there. Read up on AJAX in general too, and understand why cross-domain requests create security issues.

Comment: But i dont know how the referenced javascript file will fetch data and render it in others website place.

Comment: (Use @halfer otherwise I won't see your messages).

Comment: To fetch data: use JSONP. To render it, you need to inject HTML into the DOM, using innerHTML or similar. Frameworks like jQuery will simplify it for you. Really, if you are willing to search for this, the techniques you need are out there already.

Comment: Can you pls provide me any good tutorial link for this to understand it better?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to let other websites embed an iframe showing **some** content from your website but not the **entire** website. What you could do (though probably not the only solution) is to take the content you want to share, say a blog post, and make that into a standalone HTML page.

So create a page with URL `foobar.com/blog/post1` but it only contains the post, not your entire website layout, navbar, footer etc. (This will be the case if you are using a MVC or making a SPA website). Make sure to include necessary styles and scripts with it too.

This can then be included in an iframe: `<iframe src="http://foobar.com/blog/post1"></iframe>`

Another alternative is to write an API where the other websites can request your blog post (or pictures, content or whatever) as .JSON objects, possibly containing the HTML as a string.

Really there are quite a few options depending on it being static or dynamic content. For dynamic I would suggest to use an iframe containing the mini app, which gets updated data through an API, or maybe even websockets if it has to be live.

And don't forget to deal with CORS on your server.

---

**EDIT**

So you want to offer a JS file for other's to include in their code similarly to requesting a JS library from a CDN:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js
```

In this case you can load a JS file from somebody's server. Similarly you offer a JS file for the other websites to include. This JS will load content from your server via a HTTP request. There are many libraries which facilitate this, try learning about JQuery Ajax[(tutoriallink)](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development/).

Then as @halfer suggested, you ask the website owner to have a `div` with a unique id, say `'your_website_name'` which your JS script searches for and populates with data received from your server.

```
<div id="your_website_name"> </div>
```

**Note:**

Your question was very vague so don't hate on the SO community trying to help. In the comments they added ideas to spur on other users' answers, otherwise they would have posted an answer.

I think what you are actually searching for is how to populate HTML via JS, and pull data via the network as you seem to know the rest. Read up on these terms, maybe look at some JS libraries such as [JQUERY](http://jquery.com/), [Mootools](http://mootools.net/) or even [MVC](http://todomvc.com/) frameworks if your "applet" is quite complex.

If you want more help, post a new and **more specific** question about your use-case, any code you have written so far helps too.

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't follow it too much. I don't think I can do it by reading this solution. Between I saw some websites also offer their content to display in others websites using script tag. They say to paste a script tag referencing some file much like we include any external JavaScript file. How do they do that? I want to mention I am using PHP as a server-side language.

Comment: In addition to my edit, you mention how to generate the code via php: the script has to be written in JS and once it is loaded by other websites it should request data from the PHP server, so you are writing a HTTP GET or POST endpoint, not a JS script generator.